# How to view API query from ElasticSearch response using c# Nest 2.0

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm upgrading to NEST 2.0 from 1.7 and I cant view the actual generated query in the results object.

I'm calling an async operation from my C# code like this:
var results = await _elasticClientWrapper.Client.SearchAsync(descriptor =>
                descriptor.From(itemSearchDto.From).... etc

I'm getting results back ie a list of documents but there appears to be no way to view the actual query that was generated.

With the previous NEST version (7.1) I could do this and it was very useful.

Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` on `ConnectionSettings` passed to the constructor of `ElasticClient`. The request bytes and response bytes will then be available on the response as `.CallDetails.RequestBodyInBytes` and `.CallDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes`, respectively.

To get the json, use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)`.

[The documentation on connecting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connecting.html) has more detail.